# Are there any pan-social laws?

Tags: law, political-theory

If you think about the massive difference of political opinion on your country and then in the world, you notice that there are very few things everyone agrees on.

From my UK perspective I can only think of *Don't kill innocents for no reason*, *Don't steal from others without reason* and that is almost it. Values that I would personally hope to be universal, such as *Don't rape*, *Don't discriminate* are, unfortunately, not agreed with universally.

Are there any **truly universal** laws?

That's probably impossible; what about if you exclude anarchists and fringe extremists, are there any then?

Comment: Seems more suited for philosophy.se

Comment: Don't cheat on your wive(s) or your husband seems to be very universal to me.

Comment: @Bregalad - Philosophically/ethically, France would like to have a conversation with you about your (un)civilized views on marital (in)fidelity :) Legally, very few countries outside Middle East actually have - AND actually apply - laws about infidelity at this point.

Comment: @Bregalad - "Studies suggest around 30–40% of unmarried relationships and 18–20% of marriages see at least one incident of sexual infidelity" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infidelity

Comment: @user4012 - This is a question about theory, not practice. If we could prove that there was a value common to all societies which said not to cheat on spouses, that would not imply anything about how common the practice is.

Comment: Gravity?  Thermodynamics?  I'd imagine most, is not all, countries would have something along the lines of "pay your taxes".

Comment: @indigochild - the question asks about laws, not values, as far as I can tell. The latter would seem to be more sociology than politics, in any case.

Comment: The question is interesting, my main objection would be that **true universal** laws would be so universal that nobody would need making them explicit. It would be like putting in the Criminal Code: "1) You must follow the Law of Gravity. 2) You may not exceed the speed of light" If *everyone* agrees and *nobody* breaks them, then no law is needed.

Comment: To put a (somewhat related) example, for many years there was no law stablishing which was the official language of France because nobody saw the need for such a law.

Comment: "Don't kill innocents for no reason" - I find it interesting that you added "for no reason". So what are valid reasons to kill innocents in the UK? (I assume from the context that you mean intentional, avoidable killing/murder in so far as the murderer has a choice about the matter...)

Comment: A lot of things "we wish were universal" are often **extraordinarily** difficult to define in an objective manner.  For a very strong example, consider the "right to life" argument the US is grappling with.  Everyone agrees that killing is a bad thing, but there is not an agreement as to when a blob of cells becomes a thing that can be killed.  Any attempt to draw a dividing line on this topic gets mired in details because there is no perfect line with no pathological behavior.

Comment: The definition of "stealing" is also relative. What things are considered to be individual property? Where does group property fit in? etc. In fact, as with murder (defined as not-ok killing), we can define stealing as "not-ok taking of things [which may include people]". It's likely that some kinds of taking are always OK, but what they are varies.

Comment: @AnoE - collateral damage during a military operation is often considered a possibly acceptable reason to kill innocents, provided great efforts are made to avoid it but it proves impossible and the objective is important enough. Accidentally killing an innocent is  considered less of a crime than deliberately (e.g. if a cop - being in UK that's unlikely but sill - shoots at a criminal but misses and hits a bystander). Heat-of-the-moment is considered less of a crime than premeditated murder.

Comment: @user4012, I find that notion very debatable. Both collateral damage and heat-of-the-moment murder is not acceptable in any fashion whatsoever, for me, and likely a sizeable amount of the population. We are in a topic discussion "pan-social" laws; this would assume that at least an overwhelming part of society agrees with them, don't you think?

Comment: @AnoE - as long as a majority (or even a meaningfully large minority) thinks it is acceptable, **it can't be considered universal**. Your personal acceptance isn't meaningful in that context. As such, "for no reason" was a valid addendum, which is what your comment was complaining about.

Comment: @user4012, I really do not understand what you mean to say. I do know that what you wrote in your question and in the "collateral damage" seems wholly wrong to me, on any level (both morally as well as logically).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are called [Cultural Universals](https://www.boundless.com/sociology/textbooks/boundless-sociology-textbook/culture-3/culture-and-society-29/cultural-universals-184-5913/) or expressed negatively as taboos.  The attached article includes the taboo of incest as example, which is defined differently among cultures.  The other two near universal taboos are cannibalism and murder, again what constitutes these acts varies from culture to culture and the fact that they do occur is not to detract from the fact that most, or all, societies see these as crimes.

> The concept of a cultural universal has long been discussed in the social sciences. Cultural universals are elements, patterns, traits, or institutions that are common to all human cultures worldwide. There is a tension in cultural anthropology and cultural sociology between the claim that culture is a universal (the fact that all human societies have culture), and that it is also particular (culture takes a tremendous variety of forms around the world).

Source: Boundless. “Cultural Universals.” Boundless Sociology. Boundless, 01 Jul. 2016. Retrieved 26 Oct. 2016 from https://www.boundless.com/sociology/textbooks/boundless-sociology-textbook/culture-3/culture-and-society-29/cultural-universals-184-5913/

This article lists the top taboos in the world: https://popculture.knoji.com/top-10-taboos-in-world/

Comment: Isn't incest common in some cultures?

Comment: No.  From the second article: Incest is one of the most common taboos across cultures. Among incestuous relationships, parent-child and sibling-sibling unions are the most abhorred ones. Though incest occurred among many cultures sporadically throughout history, modern age has seen the steep decline of formally practiced incest.

Comment: @KDog - Is that because those cultures naturally abhorred incest, or because *Western* culture has imposed its own taboo on them?  I tend to be highly suspicious of anything cultural in the "modern age".

Comment: That link. Stopped reading at "Human beings consider heterosexual relationships excluding incest as normal. All other sexual preferences and practices are considered abnormal and have strong taboos attached to them". Actually, continued reading. "Murdering another human being is considered an extreme act unless it is in war or in self-defense" - tell that to the victims of genocides (recently... ex-Jugoslavia, South Africa...).

Comment: ... it gets hillarious at "There is a strong social taboo against eating meat of carnivorous animals. Exceptions include bear, fox, dog, crocodile, shark, most fish and duck.".

Comment: Its worth noting that there's a large difference between "near universal" and "universal" in questions like these.  As you point out, cannibalism is "near universal," but there are cultures where we had to teach people to stop eating eachother so they'd stop getting sick!  Also interesting is the difference between killing and murder.  Murder is always defined to be a killing that the group finds inexusable, so its status as a "universal taboo" is almost a tautology.

Comment: @Bobson Or is it that incest generally has negative genetic effects, and the urge for incest has been bred out of society due to reduced fitness of the offspring?

Comment: @Bobson It's near universal.  Now certain cultures will define incest differently.  For example Muslims encourage the marriage of cousins.  https://wikiislam.net/wiki/Cousin_Marriage_in_Islam However there is a strong taboo against sex with one's own children.

Answer (score 1):

> Don't kill innocents for no reason, Don't steal from others without reason

How's a "reason" defined? is "because I want to" a reason? How do you decide which reason is valid and which is not? Is it ok to kill innocents to appease the gods of rain? What about killing innocents to prevent a war?

Some places may consider belonging to a different race or creed reason enough to steal from people, while other places may not. In such cases, even if the rule is "Don't steal from others without reason", is it really the same rule when the reference frame, and the set of values under which it is applied, are different?

I think that there is no such thing as a pan-social law. Not in humans, anyway.